# What is the proper way to bind a filepicker.io modal view to a Bootstrap 3 component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, filepicker.io

This is something that has been a bother to me for a while. Is there a proper way to bind a filepicker.io element or modal view to a Bootstrap (2 or 3) component (e.g. a button) that doesn't cause any bizarre visual appearances? I've shuffled through the documentation available for both filepicker.io and Bootstrap (2 & 3), and have used the method for creating a filepicker.io widget.
This works, but makes an awkward visual appearance and doesn't have any objects bound to a Bootstrap (2 or 3) element. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

check out Jansy's build - http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

You can extend your current bootstrap with a small add-on file, which is nice.  I use it for file uploads... it's beautiful.

Comment: Wow, this is an excellent resource! In using it w/ Rails, is filepicker-rails (https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails) required?

Comment: No.  I've never used a gem with uploads.  `<%= form_tag upload_somewhere_path, multipart: true do %>` `<%= file_field_tag :file %>` `<% end %>`

Comment: eh... I see what you're using there.  That's pretty neat.  that gem / plugin gives you some pretty sweet functionality.  I haven't done any post-processing on images though, just get it to s3, and handle sizing with ec2.  Seems like it would work together, though.

Comment: Alright! Also, how do I get the "extend" package from Jansy Bootstrap?

Comment: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/ - extend... grab the css file, and the js file.  plop them into your assets pipeline, stylesheets and javascripts, respectively.

Comment: Ah.. thanks for the assistance! Though not a complete answer, this will prove extremely helpful!